# Stop downloading files on page load

Tags: php, forms

I have the following grabber that is downloading empty files and saving them to my folder.  So i have like 20k video files that are all 40kb each.  how can i get it so this script will not DL until form submit.

```
$rename = substr(md5(rand(0,9999)), 17, 10); 
$ch = curl_init("$vid");
$fp = fopen("$rename.m4v", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
$url_insert = "/dom/";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['some-form-item'])){

$rename = substr(md5(rand(0,9999)), 17, 10); 
$ch = curl_init("$vid");
$fp = fopen("$rename.m4v", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
$url_insert = "/dom/";

}
```

that will only run if the form as been posted with something in it, change the if at the top to what ever item is being posteD?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

$rename = substr(md5(rand(0,9999)), 17, 10); 
$ch = curl_init("$vid");
$fp = fopen("$rename.m4v", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
$url_insert = "/dom/";

}
```

In order for this to work, the name element of your submit button must be set to submit.

I.e.: `<input type="submit" name="submit" />`